# Maven Release Plugin Jenkins Keeps Copying Trunk into Tag instead of Branch

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

I need to release an older branch to satisfy a dependency that a different team have. The setup is through Jenkins using maven-release plugin.
As the title suggests all goes well until it reaches the copy to tag phase in which instead of copying over the branch it copies the trunk and fails when trying to build it as the trunk is setup to deploy to a different nexus.

Please help I have been racking my brain for almost an entire day day now.

Current jenkins GOAL:

-X -DdryRun=${DRY_RUN_MODE} -DbranchName=release_1.243  -Dapp.svn.repo=${APP_SVN_REPO} clean release:prepare release:perform

Current config:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <branchName>release_1.243</branchName>
                    <tagNameFormat>release_branch_@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <scm>
        <connection>${project.svn.repo}/trunk</connection>
        <!-- Because we have a single-module SVN repo with a FLAT multi-module
            file structure, we need to point to this parent pom's folder in the developer
            connection, not the root (trunk) repo. -->
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:${project.svn.repo}/trunk/app-parent</developerConnection>
    </scm>
```

Comment: If you are working on a branch than you should change the scm parts to the according branch ?

Comment: I figured out before I could read your comment but you are indeed correct. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
connection>${mach.svn.repo}/branches/release_1.243</connection>
        <!-- Because we have a single-module SVN repo with a FLAT multi-module
            file structure, we need to point to this parent pom's folder in the developer
            connection, not the root (trunk) repo. -->
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:${mach.svn.repo}/branches/release_1.243/efx-parent</developerConnection>
```

That solved it but  khmarbaise should get credit even though I did solve it before I could read his comment.